# Hello World in JOGL

Tags: java, jogl

I'm new to both `Java` and `Jogl`, and recently ran across the following error:

ERROR for first line of code:

```
"The import net cannot be resolved"
```

2ND LINE:

```
Multiple markers at this line
  - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
  - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

In other words the code's brackets and parenthesis are unbalanced.

```
import net.java.games.jogl.*;
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    try {
      System.loadLibrary("jogl");
      System.out.println(
        "Hello World! (The native libraries are installed.)"
      );
```

With the code now indented, it is apparent that I have a couple missing `}`'s.  I have learned my lesson and will indent my code from now on.

Comment: you didn't close the `try` `main()` or `HelloWorld` blocks. You should read up on some general Java tutorial before diving headfirst into a library like JOGL. Also depending on you IDE you have to import the JOGL library or set the classpath. It also says exactly what you did wrong here `In other words the code's brackets and parenthesis are unbalanced.` You need a `}` to match every `{` which you don't have, also you are missing the `catch` block for the `try` block

Comment: Hi, take a look to this [Hello Triangle](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle)

Answer (score 1):

Classes don't have an access modified: `public class HelloWorld` should be `class HelloWorld`.

Your braces don't match up - you've opened some, but not closed them. It should look something like this:

```
public class HelloWorld
{ // open HelloWorld

    public static void main (String args[])
    { // open main
        try
        { // open try
            System.loadLibrary("jogl");
            System.out.println("Hello World! (The native libraries are installed.)");
        } // close try
        catch (Exception e) // all try's need a catch
        { } // even if the catch does nothing
    } // close main

} // close HelloWorld
```

As to the import not being resolved, pass. Someone else will drop by who knows more about this specific problem than I do :)

Comment: you forgot his import and there's no `catch` block behind the `try`

Comment: Mentioned the import at the end of the post. Good catch on the missing `catch` though :)

Comment: Can someone explain to me what this error means? The nested type HelloWorld cannot hide an enclosing type @Joe ?

Comment: You can't define a `public class` in another class. Meaning that if you have `class SOMETHING {` before you write `public class HelloWorld` you have to close the block with a`}`. But like I said, go read a normal java tutorial you are making this more difficult for yourself than it has to be.